# Is there a way to test Server Sent Events in Rails 4 with Cucumber/Capybara/Poltergeist?

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, ruby-on-rails-4, poltergeist

I have Rails 4 with ActionController::Live, I have everything working properly and I have text writing to the screen. I have done a lot of searching and looking for a capybara driver that can handle server sent events. The result is that the capybara will hang up when you visit a page. Has anyone worked with this before?

Comment: Were you able to unit test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether this is possible with Poltergeist. I guess it will depend on whether the WebKit version in PhantomJS is new enough to support SSE. I'd try to test for SSE support in PhantomJS as a first step.